# terminal extrac words ending with ".abc" from file

Tags: bash, file, text, terminal, osx-mavericks

I want to do the following through the terminal. I have a file with many lines, each line containing a whole sentence. Some lines are empty. I want to read the file and extract all words that end with `.abc`. I want to do this through the terminal. How might I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` can be very usefull

```
$ cat input

.abc
.abdadf
assadf.abc
adsfas.abcadf
asdf.abc

$ grep -o '\b[^\.]*\.abc\b' input

assadf.abc
asdf.abc
```

**What it does**

- `-o` prints the string in the line which match the regex given
- `\b[^\.]*\.abc\b` regex matches any word wich ends with `.abc`

  - `\b` word boundary
  - `[^\.]` anything other than a `.`
  - `*` matches zero or more
  - `\.abc\b` matches `.abc` followed by word boundary `\b`

**Note**

If the word can contain more than one `.` then modify the regex as

`\b.*\.abc\b`

where `.*` would match anything including `.`

Answer (score 1):

To find all the words that ends with `.abc`.

```
grep -oP '\S*\.abc(?=\s|$)' file
```

- `\S*` Zero or more non-space charcaters.
- `(?=\s|$)` Positive lookahead asserts that the character following the match must be a space or end of the line anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk` among various other possibities.

```
awk '/\.abc$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed command also.

```
sed -n '/\.abc$/ p' file
```